# Kotlin suspendCoroutine

Tags: kotlin

I try to understand the documentation of [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html).

> In this function both Continuation.resume and Continuation.resumeWithException can be used either synchronously in the same stack-frame where the suspension function is run or asynchronously later in the same thread or from a different thread of execution.

This sounds to me like: "resume can be used everywhere".

Is there anything left, I am not aware of?

Update for the closing gang having problems to understand anything: The documentation list three restrictions:

1. synchronously
2. asynchronously
3. in other thread

The question is: why are the restrictions enumerated, if the sum of all restricitons is no restriction?

Comment: *why are the restrictions enumerated, if the sum of all restricitons is no restriction?* - these are not framed as "restrictions" in the doc, rather a clarification about what is possible. The benefit of doing that is that you can quickly confirm that your use case is indeed covered. An analogy would be a function taking an int, with a doc saying the int can be negative, 0, or positive. Technically it means no restrictions, but it ensures all those cases are valid, and clears doubts about whether some undocumented restrictions existed.

Comment: @Joffrey Sorry but this makes as much sense as adding the sentence: you can use resume with less than 16 megabyte RAM and more then 8 megabyte RAM.

Comment: I think you're not answering in good faith here. When using functions related to concurrency, it's typical to ask yourself questions about whether something is thread-safe, can be called asynchronously, or from other threads etc. it's less likely you would require information about how much RAM should be free to call it (at least in this context). You're asking *"Is there anything left I am not aware of?"*, but did you face an actual case where you needed to call `resume` but weren't sure this was valid? Because the main goal of the doc is to clarify doubts about actual usage IMO.

Comment: But I have a question, how would you have phrased this piece of the doc? Do you have a clearer wording that doesn't imply enumeration, but still is crystal clear as to what you can do with it? *"resume can be used everywhere"* really doesn't cut it for me - what does everyhwere mean? Is it in the space of threads, or the space of code? Is it every**when** as well? IMO it has to be more specific. Most likely you would end up adding a parenthesis with examples for clarity, so enumerating after all.

Comment: *Update for the closing gang having problems to understand anything* - I'm not part of those people (I think your initial question was clear), yet I find this comment quite inappropriate to be frank. It would be worth rewording it.

Comment: @Joffrey About the question how to word it: I would delete it. It does not explain anything instead it confuses. And now after I know this, it sounds like advertising to me.

Comment: I personally find this piece of information crucial in the doc of such a function. If your solution is to remove it, then more people would be asking on SO about where `resume` can or cannot be called. People with practical questions can find their answer in the current doc. I think you didn't find yours because your question is theoretical, and I would almost dare to say you only find the doc confusing in theory too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can resume a continuation from anywhere.
It's an error to try and resume the same continuation more than once, though.

- If you call `resume` immediately, during the call to `suspendCoroutine`, the coroutine does not suspend.
- If you don't call resume immediately, that's what results in a coroutine suspension. The suspended coroutine then resumes when you later call `resume` from some other control flow.

The continuation you receive from `suspendCoroutine` is intercepted by the context's dispatcher. When you resume a suspended coroutine via an intercepted continuation, the coroutine resumes on the dispatcher, rather than running on the thread from which you resumed it.